# Q_ASSERT in Qt. How to get calling function

Tags: c++, qt

I am using `QVector<double>` in a lot of source files. When I run program it gives an error:

`ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:/Qt/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/qt-5.5.0-x64-mingw510r0-seh-rev0/include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 401`

I understand  what that error means. However it links to `qvector.h` whick is not helpful, because I don't know which source gives that error. How can I find which of my source files gives that error?

Comment: Run the application in debug mode through QtCreator. You will be able to see the call stack when application crashes

Comment: @Lahiru Chandima. This error happens in debug mode. In release mode there no check of `[]` operator. However in debug mode there no stack call information, `Q_ASSERT` somehow supress it.

Comment: In my QtCreator, when the app crashes due to a `Q_ASSERT`, I get a dialog to choose to abort, retry or cancel. If I press retry, QtCreator shows me a stack trace as if the program hit a breakpoint. I am on Windows and QtCreator uses visual c++ compiler. May be this feature is not available in other platforms

Comment: @Lahiru Chandima Usually the same happens In my QtCreator, but not in this case.

Comment: If nothing else works you could always search through your source and place breakpoints before each usage of QVector's [] operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using QtCreator and GCC/GDB, try setting the `Stop when qFatal() is called` option.

Steps to set the option:

1. Select `Tools -> Options` from the menu.
2. Select `Debugger` in the list on the left.
3. Select `GDB Extended` tab.
4. Check `Stop when qFatal() is called`.
5. Click `Ok`.

Run your application.  QtCreator should stop and display a stack trace when the Q_ASSERT macro evaluates to false.  You can use the stack trace to determine the file and line in your source code that called `QVector<T>::operator[]`.

I created a simple program to test.  Note the bad index `t[200]`.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector<int> t;

    t << 1;
    t << 2;

    int x = t[1];
    int y = t[200];

    return a.exec();
}
```

Without the option set, I get the debug output in the Console and QtCreator shows some assembly language.  With the option set, I get a stack trace as shown in the following image:

[image: Qt Stack Trace]

Note the stack trace indicates my problem is on line 14 in function `main` in file `main.cpp`.

`Q_ASSERT` within Qt is implemented as a macro.  `Q_ASSERT` uses`qFatal()` as noted in the documentation for `Q_ASSERT` at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_ASSERT.

Thus, setting the option will cause QtCreator to stop on `Q_ASSERT`s.

Note that the application must be built in `DEBUG` mode.  Per the documentation, the `Q_ASSERT` statements do nothing if `QT_NO_DEBUG` is set.

Tested in Windows 7 using QtCreator 3.5.1 and Qt 5.5.1.

Comment: +1 for the info, but I cant seem to get this to work, see my answer...  If it works it is a very nice and easy way to get to the problem that I was not aware of

Answer (score 2):

You can us the [qInstallMsgHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) function in Qt to also get you to where the issue happens.

If you implement the sample code on the provided link you can add something like the following in the `myMessageOutput` function:

```
if(QString(msg).conains("index out of range") == true) {
    qDebug() << "Out of range"; // <- put a breakpoint here.
}
```

If the application hits the breakpoint you can also check the stack trace to see where the issue occurred in the same way that @esorton suggested.

*PS: I was not aware of of the "GDB Extended" tab and the options in Qt Creator so this is what I normally did. The benefit of my suggestion is that you can trace any type of message like this.*

Not sure why but doing what @esorton suggested my QtC gives me an assembly `Disassembler (??)` output without any help on where the issue occurred (perhaps something is broken with my setup, Ubuntu gcc 4.8 with Qt 5.4):

```
    Function: _Z11qt_assert_xPKcS0_S0_i
0x7f0c731757ea  <+0x003a>        24 08                          and    $0x8,%al
0x7f0c731757ec  <+0x003c>        00 00                          add    %al,(%rax)
0x7f0c731757ee  <+0x003e>        00 00                          add    %al,(%rax)
0x7f0c731757f0  <+0x0040>        48 c7 44 24 10 00 00 00 00     movq   $0x0,0x10(%rsp)
0x7f0c731757f9  <+0x0049>        e8 92 52 00 00                 callq  0x7f0c7317aa90 <_ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz>
0x7f0c731757fe                   66 90                          xchg   %ax,%ax
```