# Assert Failure in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, csv, indexing

I have a program that runs through CSV files, and compiles them onto two text files, one containing all the CSV files in nifty rows, and another giving quick summaries that also ranks them. After putting everything together, I run it. After the program outputs "Doing QString", I get this message:

> ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range", file ........\5.3\mingw482_32\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 487

A copy of my program:

```
    #include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>

// Variables for the score names

#define Team                0
#define Match               1
#define Pos    2
#define AutoDefCross           3
#define AutoCrossed            4
#define HighAttempt             5
#define HighMade               6
#define LowMade              7
#define LowAttempt           8
#define TeleLow               9
#define TeleHigh           10
#define BarClear            11
#define DrawAss            12
#define DrawClear           13
#define DrawFail          14
#define MoatClear         15
#define MoatFail           16
#define PortAss              17
#define PortClear            18
#define PortFail             19
#define RamClear          20
#define RamFail             21
#define SwingAss          22
#define SwingClear            23
#define SwingFail          24
#define TeetAss           25
#define TeetClear          26
#define TeetFail         27
#define TerraClear       28
#define TerraFail       29
#define Wallclear      30
#define WallFail       31
#define Challenge      32
#define Climb         33
#define Comment        34
// Writing AllData

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        int counter=0, i, j, team;
        int teams[120], matchcount[120], autosum[120], telesum[120], totsum[120];
        int highteamauto, highteamtele, highteamtotal;
        QDir dir("C:/FRCScoutData/TabletFiles");

        QFile myoutfile("C:/FRCScoutData/alldata.csv");

        myoutfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        QTextStream outfile(&myoutfile);

        QStringList rawData;
        QStringList mylist;
// The titles of blocks in Excel, respective to lower outfile.
outfile << "Team,Match,totalscore,autoscore,telescore,Pos,AutoDefCross,AutoCross,HighAttempt,HighMade,LowMade,LowAttempt,TeleLow,TeleHigh,BarClear,DrawAss,DrawClear,DrawFail,MoatFail,PortAss,PortClear,PortFail,RamClear,RamFail,SwingAss,SwingClear,SwingFail,TeetAss,TeetClear,TeetFail,TerraClear,TerraFail,Clear,Challenge,Climb,ChevaFail,WallFail,Comment \r\n";


        if ( dir.exists() )
        {
            //set fileinfo filter
            QFileInfoList entries = dir.entryInfoList( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files );
            //loop over entries filter selected
            foreach ( QFileInfo entryInfo, entries )
            {
                QString path = entryInfo.absoluteFilePath();

                QFile csvfile(path);

                printf("Processing file %s\n", qPrintable(path));

                csvfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

                QTextStream stream(&csvfile);

                rawData.append(stream.readAll());

                mylist = rawData[counter].split(",");
                counter++;
// Defining scores, or something like that. ||||||||iI|||

                printf("Doing QString");
                QString autoscore = QString::number((mylist[AutoDefCross].toInt())           *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[AutoCrossed].toInt())            *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[HighAttempt].toInt())             *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[HighMade].toInt())         *   2+
                                                                    (mylist[LowMade].toInt())       *   2+
                                                                    (mylist[LowAttempt].toInt())         *   1);

                                QString telescore = QString::number((mylist[TeleLow].toInt())         *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[TeleHigh].toInt())          *   2+
                                                                    (mylist[BarClear].toInt())          *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[DrawAss].toInt())           *   1+
                                                                   (mylist[DrawClear].toInt())      *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[DrawFail].toInt())    *   -1+
                                                                    (mylist[MoatClear].toInt())           *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[MoatFail].toInt())   *   -1+
                                                                    (mylist[PortAss].toInt())          *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[PortClear].toInt())           *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[PortFail].toInt())       *   -1+
                                                                    (mylist[RamClear].toInt())          *  1+
                                                                    (mylist[RamFail].toInt())        *  -1+
                                                                    (mylist[SwingClear].toInt())            *  1+
                                                                    (mylist[SwingFail].toInt())        *  -1+
                                                                    (mylist[TeetAss].toInt())    *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[TeetClear].toInt())           *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[TeetFail].toInt())   *      -1+
                                                                    (mylist[TerraClear].toInt())          *   1+
                                                                    (mylist[TerraFail].toInt())           *  -1+
                                                                    (mylist[Wallclear].toInt())       *   2+
                                                                    (mylist[WallFail].toInt())          *  -1+
                                                                    (mylist[Challenge].toInt())        *  1+
                                                                    (mylist[Climb].toInt())            *    3);


                                QString totalscore = QString::number((autoscore.toInt()) +
                                                                    (telescore.toInt()));
//Actual Variables being written, AKA, Lower Outfile

                                outfile << mylist[Team] + "," + mylist[Match] + "," + totalscore + "," + autoscore + "," + telescore + "," +
                                                           mylist[Pos] + "," + mylist[AutoDefCross] + "," + mylist[AutoCrossed] + "," +
                                                           mylist[HighAttempt] + "," + mylist[HighMade] + "," + mylist[LowMade] + "," + mylist[LowAttempt] + "," +
                                                           mylist[TeleLow] + "," + mylist[TeleHigh] + "," + mylist[BarClear] + "," +
                                                           mylist[DrawAss] + "," + mylist[DrawClear] + "," + mylist[DrawFail] + "," + mylist[MoatClear] + "," +
                                                           mylist[PortAss] + "," + mylist[PortClear] + "," + mylist[PortFail] + "," +
                                                           mylist[RamClear] + "," + mylist[RamFail] + "," + mylist[SwingAss] + "," +
                                                           mylist[SwingClear] + "," + mylist[SwingFail] + "," + mylist[TeetAss]
                                                           + "," + mylist[TeetClear] + "," + mylist[TeetFail] + "," + mylist[TerraClear] + "," + mylist[TerraFail] + "," + mylist[Wallclear] +  "," + mylist[WallFail] + "," + "," + mylist[Challenge] + "," + mylist[Climb] + "," + mylist[Comment].simplified() + "\"\r\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // What happens when it fails, I think.
            qDebug() << "Missing directory C:\\FRCScoutData\\TabletFiles, You done messed up, Bro.";
        }



        myoutfile.close();

        rawData.sort();

        int lastteam = 0;
        int teamcount = 0;

        QFile mysummaryfile("C:/FRCScoutData/summarydata.csv");

        mysummaryfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        QTextStream outsumfile(&mysummaryfile);
// Begin alldata
// Excel table columns, respective to lower outfile.
        outsumfile << "Team,Match,totalscore,autoscore,telescore,Pos,AutoDefCross,AutoCross,HighAttempt,HighMade,LowMade,LowAttempt,TeleLow,TeleHigh,BarClear,DrawAss,DrawClear,DrawFail,MoatFail,PortAss,PortClear,PortFail,RamClear,RamFail,SwingAss,SwingClear,SwingFail,TeetAss,TeetClear,TeetFail,TerraClear,TerraFail,Clear,Challenge,Climb,ChevaFail,WallFail,Comment \r\n";
        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            mylist = rawData[i].split(",");

            if (lastteam != mylist[Team].toInt())
            {
                if (lastteam != 0)
                {
                    teamcount++;
                }
                teams[teamcount] = mylist[Team].toInt();
                autosum[teamcount] = 0;
                telesum[teamcount] = 0;
                totsum[teamcount] = 0;
                matchcount[teamcount] = 0;
            }
// More score definitions

            lastteam = mylist[Team].toInt();
                        matchcount[teamcount]++;

                        autosum[teamcount] +=  mylist[AutoDefCross].toInt()           *   1+
                                               mylist[AutoCrossed].toInt()            *   1+
                                               mylist[HighAttempt].toInt()             *   1+
                                               mylist[HighMade].toInt()         *   2+
                                               mylist[LowMade].toInt()       *   2+
                                               mylist[LowAttempt].toInt()         *   1;

                        telesum[teamcount] += mylist[TeleLow].toInt()         *   1+
                                              mylist[TeleHigh].toInt()          *   2+
                                              mylist[BarClear].toInt()          *   1+
                                              mylist[DrawAss].toInt()           *   1+
                                              mylist[DrawFail].toInt()      *   1+
                                              mylist[MoatClear].toInt()    *   1+
                                              mylist[MoatFail].toInt()           *   -1+
                                              mylist[PortAss].toInt()   *   1+
                                              mylist[PortClear].toInt()          *   1+
                                              mylist[PortFail].toInt()           *   -1+
                                              mylist[RamClear].toInt()       *   1+
                                              mylist[RamFail].toInt()          *  -1+
                                              mylist[SwingAss].toInt()        *  1+
                                              mylist[SwingFail].toInt()            *  -1+
                                              mylist[TeetAss].toInt()        *   1+
                                             (mylist[TeetClear].toInt())           *   1+
                                              (mylist[TeetFail].toInt())   *      -1+
                                             (mylist[TerraClear].toInt())          *   1+
                                           (mylist[TerraFail].toInt())           *  -1+
                                           (mylist[Wallclear].toInt())       *   2+
                                           (mylist[WallFail].toInt())          *  -1+
                                           (mylist[Challenge].toInt())        *  1+
                                            (mylist[Climb].toInt())            *    3;


                        totsum[teamcount] +=  mylist[AutoDefCross].toInt()           *   1+
                                mylist[AutoCrossed].toInt()            *   1+
                                mylist[HighAttempt].toInt()             *   1+
                                mylist[HighMade].toInt()         *   2+
                                mylist[LowMade].toInt()       *   2+
                                mylist[LowAttempt].toInt()         *   1+

                                (mylist[TeleLow].toInt())         *   1+
                                (mylist[TeleHigh].toInt())          *   2+
                                (mylist[BarClear].toInt())          *   1+
                                (mylist[DrawAss].toInt())           *   1+
                                (mylist[DrawClear].toInt())      *   1+
                                (mylist[DrawFail].toInt())    *   -1+
                                (mylist[MoatClear].toInt())           *   1+
                                (mylist[MoatFail].toInt())   *   -1+
                                (mylist[PortAss].toInt())          *   1+
                                (mylist[PortClear].toInt())           *   1+
                                (mylist[PortFail].toInt())       *   -1+
                                (mylist[RamClear].toInt())          *  1+
                                (mylist[RamFail].toInt())        *  -1+
                                (mylist[SwingClear].toInt())            *  1+
                                (mylist[SwingFail].toInt())        *  -1+
                                (mylist[TeetAss].toInt())    *   1+
                                (mylist[TeetClear].toInt())           *   1+
                                (mylist[TeetFail].toInt())   *      -1+
                                (mylist[TerraClear].toInt())          *   1+
                                (mylist[TerraFail].toInt())           *  -1+
                                (mylist[Wallclear].toInt())       *   2+
                                (mylist[WallFail].toInt())          *  -1+
                                (mylist[Challenge].toInt())        *  1+
                                (mylist[Climb].toInt())            *    3;

        }


        for (team=0; team <= teamcount; team++)
        {
           highteamauto = 1;
           highteamtele = 1;
           highteamtotal = 1;
           for (j = 0; j <= teamcount; j++)
           {
               /*if ((float(autosum[j])/float(matchcount[j])) > (float(autosum[team])/float(matchcount[team])))
               {
                   highteamauto++;
               }
               if ((float(telesum[j])/float(matchcount[j])) > (float(telesum[team])/float(matchcount[team])))
               {
                   highteamtele++;
               }
               if ((float(endsum[j])/float(matchcount[j])) > (float(endsum[team])/float(matchount[team])))
               {
                   highteamend++;
               {
               if ((float(totsum[j])/float(matchcount[j])) > (float(totsum[team])/float(matchcount[team])))
               {
                   highteamtotal = highteamtotal + 1;
               }
               */
               if ((autosum[j]/matchcount[j]) > (autosum[team]/matchcount[team]))
               {
                   highteamauto++;
               }
               if ((telesum[j]/matchcount[j]) > (telesum[team]/matchcount[team]))
               {
                   highteamtele++;
               }
               if ((totsum[j]/matchcount[j]) > (totsum[team]/matchcount[team]))
               {
                   highteamtotal = highteamtotal + 1;
               }
           }

           // Output summary record, AKA, Lower Outfile
                      outsumfile << QString::number(teams[team])      + "," +
                                    QString::number(matchcount[team]) + "," +
                                    mylist[HighMade].toInt()       + "," +
                                    mylist[LowMade].toInt()       + "," +
                                    mylist[TeleHigh].toInt()       + "," +
                                    mylist[TeleLow].toInt()       + "," +
                                    mylist[BarClear].toInt()       + "," +
                                    mylist[Climb].toInt()       + "," +
                                    mylist[Comment].toInt()       + "," +
                                    QString::number(autosum[team])    + "," +
                                    QString::number(float(autosum[team])/float(matchcount[team]), 'f', 1) + "," +
                                    QString::number(telesum[team])    + "," +
                                    QString::number(float(telesum[team])/float(matchcount[team]), 'f', 1) + "," +
                                    QString::number(totsum[team])     + "," +
                                    QString::number(float(totsum[team])/float(matchcount[team]), 'f', 1)  + "," +
                                    QString::number(highteamauto)     + "," +
                                    QString::number(highteamtele)     + "," +
                                    QString::number(highteamtotal)    + "\r\n";

                      qDebug() << QString::number(teams[team])      + "," +
                                  QString::number(matchcount[team]) + "," +
                                  mylist[HighMade].toInt()       + "," +
                                  mylist[LowMade].toInt()       + "," +
                                  mylist[TeleHigh].toInt()       + "," +
                                  mylist[TeleLow].toInt()       + "," +
                                  mylist[BarClear].toInt()       + "," +
                                  mylist[Climb].toInt()       + "," +
                                  mylist[Comment].toInt()       + "," +
                                  QString::number(autosum[team])    + "," +
                                  QString::number(float(autosum[team])/float(matchcount[team]), 'f', 1) + "," +
                                  QString::number(telesum[team])    + "," +
                                  QString::number(float(telesum[team])/float(matchcount[team]), 'f', 1) + "," +
                                  QString::number(totsum[team])     + "," +
                                  QString::number(float(totsum[team])/float(matchcount[team]), 'f', 1)  + "," +
                                  QString::number(highteamauto)     + "," +
                                  QString::number(highteamtele)     + "," +
                                  QString::number(highteamtotal)    + "\r\n";

        }

        mysummaryfile.close();
}
```

Forgive the mess, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Q\_ASSERT in Qt. How to get calling function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079261/q-assert-in-qt-how-to-get-calling-function)

Comment: If you want this to be read you need to reduce it to a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Check that every line in `QFile csvfile` contains the correct number of entries. I'd put my money on there being a comma missing somewhere. The error is stating that the index is out of range, and the range of `QStringList mylist` is being set by the number of fields created with `rawData[counter].split(",");`. Perhaps you could have the program output `myList.size()` on each iteration and make sure that you are getting consistent output (which in this case I think should be 35.